# If all the nodes in a blockchain network fall down, could the blockchain be restored again?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, smartcontracts, bitcoin

If all the nodes in a blockchain network fall down, could the blockchain be restored all the history blocks again?
if it can ,could you please explain how the blocks store in the blocks and where . in databese or file ?

If all the nodes in a blockchain network fall down, could the blockchain be restored all the history blocks again?
if it can ,could you please explain how the blocks store in the blocks and where . in databese or file ?

Answer (score 0):

Each full bitcoin node has a database for blocks, and if all nodes go down, it would be a matter of syncing with the network (other full nodes) again.